# How to create simple Hello World Application taking 2 parameters

Tags: java

Hello I am a bit confused on simple method. I know how to write "Hello world" but How can I take 2 parameters outside: one is "hello", the other one is for the name.

The expected output is: `Hello <name>`

Is it going to be take 2 scanner or do I need to write a method?

thank you

Comment: Can you share your Code how you tried to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    String str1, str2;
      System.out.println ("1 Input");
      str1 = input ();
      System.out.println ("2 Input");
      str1 = input ();
  }
  public static String input ()
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    return sc.next ();
  }
}
```

like this..

Answer (score 2):

```
 String str1, str2;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println ("1 Input");
      str1 = sc.next ();
      System.out.println ("1 Input");
      str2 = sc.next ();
      System.out.println (str1 + str2);
```

**Answer of your question**

Comment: Actually I know this my question was how to do this with methods ?

Comment: use import java.util.Scanner; out side of class